# Shell script does not run with keyboard shortcut

Tags: 18.04, bash, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors, DVI-0 and DVI-1, and I only use one at a time. They are in different rooms in the house and I'd like to switch between them with a keyboard shortcut. I've made the following shell script to change to the non-active monitor:

```
current_display=$(xrandr | sed -n 's/^\(.*\) connected primary.*$/\1/p')

if [ "$current_display" == "DVI-0" ]
then
 xrandr --output DVI-1 --auto --primary
 xrandr --output DVI-0 --off 
elif [ "$current_display" == "DVI-1" ]
then
 xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto --primary
 xrandr --output DVI-1 --off 
fi
```

I saved this as /home/username/Documents/SwitchDisplay.sh and made it executable. When running `/home/username/Documents/SwitchDisplay.sh` from a terminal it does what I want it to do. But when I assign `/home/username/Documents/SwitchDisplay.sh` to a keyboard shortcut (ctrl+alt+s) using the Settings/Devices/Keyboard options in Ubuntu it does not work.

I checked if the shortcut works by assigning the command
`firefox` to the shortcut and that works fine. When I press the keyboard shortcut firefox opens. I even added `firefox` to a new line in the shell script and assigned the shell script to the shortcut again, then pressing the shortcut also opens firefox. So it does run the shell script, but the important part of the shell script is not working properly.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: see if providing the full path `/usr/bin/xrandr ... ` works? and also for the `/usr/bin/sed ... ` also adds `#! /bin/bash` at first line

Comment: try using the full path to xrandr. From the shell in which your script works run `which xrandr` and put that into your script `eg. /usr/bin/xrandr/ --output....`. See if that helps.

Comment: I ran ```which xrandr```, which gave ```/usr/bin/xrandr```. I changed all the xrandr commands to the full path commands, i.e. ```/usr/bin/xrandr --output...```, in the shell script and tested the shell script in the terminal, which worked. But using the keyboard shortcut still does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using double equal sign in your script if-clauses. That is a bashism (it's fine on BASH, but will fail in other shells). I believe the script is being handled by `dash` and not `bash`, so replace `==` with `=` and give it a try.

You avoid that "shell indetermination" by adding a shebang in the first line of the script, indicating the shell to be used. If you tried `#!/bin/bash`, as suggested in the comments, the shortcut with your original script should work. But if you can make your code more portable (with single equal instead of double), why not?

---

Some bashisms: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Oh, and that's a pretty nice wiki to learn solid shell scripting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using ```=``` instead of ```==``` solved it. Tricky nuances... I'm starting out with shell scripting and there is a lot of incomplete information on the internet, especially when you consider these details like ```dash``` or ```bash```. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Yeah, you will gradually grasp those nuances. I added a useful reference about it on my answer. Glad to help you.